# How to pass params to a model query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app with 1 user has many to many relationship with challenges via a Subscription table (which has user_id and challenge_id fields). 1 user also has many Relationships (with columns follower_id and followed_id).

I am trying to create a query in my challenges model which allows me to retrieve all users and their relationships that are part of a specific challenge. The challenge has been passed in params from my view. I should also mention that the query has to be returned in a specific json format as below.

The query should say: select all the users and their relationships who have a challenge_id that is the same as the params Challenge.find(params[:id])

My question is how to use the id of the challenge passed in the param to perform a query in my model. Also I've just realised that I don't really know how to query across many to many relationships. I tried below but I think its a mess. I suppose what I'm trying to do here is get the users pertaining to a challenge from params and then add user id and the relationship fields to the array.

The output I'm expecting is something like:

```
{"nodes":["1","2","3"],"edges":[["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","1"]]}
```

The models and their relationships are as follows- I know its a bit work-in-progress but the relevant associations are there:

[image]

the models:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         acts_as_commontator
         acts_as_messageable

  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subscribers
  has_many :challenges, through: :subscribers
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name:  "Relationship", dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :posts

  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
    foreign_key: "follower_id",
    dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
    foreign_key: "followed_id",
    dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :challenges

  def reciprocal_followers
    self.followers & self.followed_users
  end

  #For D3
  # def self.including_relationships
  #   result={}
  #   result["nodes"]=User.select(:name, :group, :id).map{|u| {name: u.name, group: u.group, id: u.id} }
  #   result["links"]=Relationship.select('follower_id as source, followed_id as target, value').map{|x| {source: x.source, target: x.target, value: x.value} }
  #   result
  # end

  def self.including_relationships
    result={}
    result["nodes"] = User.all.map {|u| u.id.to_s}
    result["edges"] = Relationship.all.map { |r| [r.follower_id.to_s, r.followed_id.to_s] } 
    result
  end

  #To add scores together
  def overall_score
    self.FBScore + self.PIScore
  end

  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end

  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end
end
```

subscriber.rb

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :challenge
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

challenge.rb

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :entries
    has_many :users, through: :subscribers
    has_many :subscribers
    belongs_to :user
end
```

### This is the part I can't figure out:

```
def self.including_relationships

  users.subscribers.includes(Challenge.find(params[:id])).each do |user|
    result={}
    result["nodes"] = User.all.map {|u| u.id.to_s}
    result["edges"] = Relationship.all.map { |r| [r.follower_id.to_s, r.followed_id.to_s] } 
    result
  end

end
```

### Update using @Athar's code -although this currently gives me the wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) error

Challenge.rb

```
def self.joinup(id)
  c = Challenge.find(id)
  result={}
  user_ids  =  c.users.pluck(:id)
  result["nodes"] = user_ids.collect(&:to_s)
  result["edges"] = Relationship.where(follower_id: user_ids).map{|h| [h.follower_id.to_s, h.followed_id.to_s]}
  result
 end
```

challenge_controller.rb

```
def join
     @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
     @challenge.users << current_user
     @users = Challenge.joinup
         respond_to do |format|
         format.html # index.html.erb
         format.json {  render json: @users } 
     end
     #Actually I want to redirect through to create json from a node edge query in the model based on the users who have joined up to that challenge.
     #So firstly I need to create the model to query the database and produce the json structure....Where do I do this ?in challenges model or can I use the users model.
     #Then I need to produce json in this controller action using similar to user controller index.
     #Then I need to render the view in a my challenges page.
  end
```

Comment: Can you add the actual code for your models so we don't have to guess how you have set up the relations? Code in general is a lot easier to read than someone trying to describe what it does.

Comment: And also the relevant portion of your schema.rb?

Comment: I've uploaded a railroady picture of the models which hopefully is more succinct, but happy to provide the code if needed as well if this isn't adequate

Comment: Railway diagram are ok as a compliment but how you have set up the relationships in rails is pretty important. So please add the relevant models.

Comment: Code updated as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this help.

please add this method to any model. i would suggest `challenge` model and from controller pass the id to the model.

```
def self.including_relationships(id)
  c = Challenge.find(id)
  result={}
  user_ids  =  c.users.pluck(:id)
  result["nodes"] = user_ids.collect(&:to_s)
  result["edges"] = Relationship.where(follower_id: user_ids).map{|h| [h.follower_id.to_s, h.followed_id.to_s]}
  result
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the error 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'. I have posted the exact code I am using now with your amendments

Comment: @SebastianZeki are you sending the id as parameter from where you are calling.? i think that is the issue.

Comment: OK I think its sorted now, all I had to do was to add Challenge.joinup(@challenge) instead of  Challenge.joinup in the controller. Pretty much as you suggested. Thanks again Athar